# using saxon in Altova

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, altova

I'm using Altova XML Spy for XML Transformation. But now i need to use SAXON processor, i have downloaded and installed SAXON.
Following the manual in Altova website [here](http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spyenterprise/index.html?xsl.htm), i've followd the same steps.

But here i'm getting an error as below.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: An Error occurred while trying to start the debugger! (An error occurred while loading the XML file)
```

please let me know how can i fix this and do a transformation.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure Altova supports debugging XSLT with other than your own engine? http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spyenterprise/index.html?xsxsltxq_debugger.htm suggests it works with their "built-in Altova XSLT" engines. I would ask in their support forums to make sure. As for Saxon, which version of Saxon exactly did you install? The documentation you linked to mentions a `saxon.exe` for XSLT 1.0. It does not look like they describe plugging in the .NET or Java version of Saxon 9.5, the latest version of Saxon doing XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (I might be wrong) that Altova only has very rudimentary support for XSLT engines other than their own, essentially at the level of command-line invocation. If you want fully integrated support for Saxon in an IDE, including debugging capability, use oXygen or Stylus Studio.